# Error in compilation for chart.js Expected method shorthand in object literal ('{label() {...}}'

Tags: typescript, callback, chart.js

I have tried to customize the label for the tooltip of my chart.js
by adding a callback for label

```
this.options = {
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, dataChartTemperature) {
                    return 'reliability=' + dataChartTemperature.datasets[4].data[tooltipItem.index];
                }
            }
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                id: 'A',
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'left',
            }, {
                id: 'B',
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'right',
            }]
        }
};
```

Compilation result in the following error

> INFO] ERROR: webapp/app/entities/bc-qualified-hourly-sample-my-suffix/bc-qualified-hourly-sample-my-suffix.component.ts[323, 21]: Expected method shorthand in object literal ('{label() {...}}').

I have no idea, how to solve it. If I remove the tooltip callback, the program compiles well.

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a TSLint error there, rather than a TypeScript error.

It wants you to change:

```
 label: function(tooltipItem, dataChartTemperature) {
```

To:

```
 label: (tooltipItem, dataChartTemperature) => {
```

This would only impact you if there is some scoped item in there that could be lost by a change of context, but I guess TSLint *hearts* arrow functions.

This is the [TSLint object-shorthand rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/object-literal-shorthand/) I think you are triggering, along with how to change it if you want to.